# PHP Pear Mail Returns Fatal Error: Failed opening required 'Mail.php'

Tags: php, email, pear

How to include mail.php for using PHP Pear Mail. I'm using the following code in test.php file:

```
    require_once "Mail.php";

    $from = "<test@gmail.com>";
    $to = "<testing@gmail.com>";
    $subject = "Hi!";
    $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

    $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
    $port = "465";
    $username = "<testtest@gmail.com>";
    $password = "testtest";

    $headers = array ('From' => $from,
      'To' => $to,
      'Subject' => $subject);
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
      array ('host' => $host,
        'port' => $port,
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password));

    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
      echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
    } else {
      echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
    }
```

and the following error is encountered via this code:

```
  Warning: require_once(Mail.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Hosting\6525150\html\test.php on line 3

  Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Mail.php' (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in D:\Hosting\6525150\html\test.php on line 3
```

Can someone tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check if pear is installed in the system . If yes then specify path to Pear installation directory in php.ini include_path directive

You need to install PEAR and PEAR MAIL packages to get it working

Comment: pear is installed on my server. and the include path is ";C:\php5\pear"

Comment: you need to install Mail package too

Comment: also check php include_path using phpinfo();

Comment: I had the same issue where I had PEAR but not Mail package, after searching for a bit the installation of Mail is quite simple:

pear install Mail

Answer (score 22):

Your error message is self-explanatory. Make sure you have PEAR::Mail installed on your machine, if not then please install it.

Linux:

> pear install Mail

Windows:

> http://www.geeksengine.com/article/install-pear-on-windows.html

If the process is done.

Then please include your Mail.php in your script (probably before you instantiate `Mail` object. This should probably kick your warnings away.

> include "/path/to/pear/Mail.php";

or

> set_include_path("/path/to/pear");
>   include "Mail.php";

Also make sure `there is enough permission` given for `Mail.php` for PHP to read.

Comment: isn't enough to do `include "Mail.php";` ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales - Yes, it is as long as you have Mail package installed on your PEAR directory.

Answer (score 0):

I pieced together these steps from the web and it works:

How to install PEAR:

`1. Download go-pear.phar at http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar & save to php directory (eg C:\Program Files\PHP\)
2. Open a command window as administrator, move to your php directory, CMD: php go-pear.phar
3. Accept the default value for everything it asks about; system wide, path options, updating your php.ini etc
4. In php directory double-click PEAR_ENV.reg to update your registry`

Then you need to install PEAR MAIL:

`5. CMD: php go-pear.phar
6. CMD: pear install --alldeps mail
7. CMD: pear channel-update pear.php.net`

Make sure to have this in your email script: require_once "Mail.php";