# Given two seperate servers; can PHP decide on the server to recieve e-mails?

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail

I've been thinking, and I have question regarding multiple e-mail addresses and the [mail](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.

Is it possible to have PHP send an email to a particular `smtp` server; for instance if I have two addresses.

**Configuration**

`smtp.fakecompany1.co.nz`

**Intended Recipient**

- `killrawr@fakecompany1.co.nz` (`smtp.fakecompany1.co.nz`)
- `killrawr@fakecompany1.co.nz` (`smtp.fakecompany2.com`)

Currently, if the `smtp` of the intended `recipient` *(smtp.fakecompany1.co.nz)* is setup then that `recipient` from the intended `smtp` *(smtp.fakecompany1.co.nz)* will receive e-mail; but my question is in regards to whether it could be possible to select an `smtp` *(smtp.fakecompany1.co.nz)* and send an *email*, without requiring to authenticate into a DIFFERENT `smtp` *(smtp.fakecompany2.com)*.

[image: email diagram]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/s4dgfswc.ghe.png))</sub>

TL;DR can I send an email from `smtp.fakecompany1.co.nz` to `smtp.fakecompany2.com` (given the email exists on both servers), without modifying the authentication details on the primary server (Due to technical issues with Gmail).

Comment: [download PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/), No need to change your php.ini!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can SMTP with PEAR::Mail instead of using  `mail()`. See this question for an example: [how to use php pear mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409516/how-to-use-php-pear-mail)

Here is a modified example I copied from the linked Q:

```
require_once "Mail.php";
$from = "<test@example.com>";
$to = "<testing@example.com>";
$subject = "Hi!";
$body = "Hello world";

$host = "smtp.fakecompany2.com";
$port = "465";
$username = "<testtest@example.com>";
$password = "testtest";

if (YOUR HEADER CHECK HERE) {
    $host = "smtp.fakecompany1.co.nz";
}

$headers = array ('From' => $from,
  'To' => $to,
  'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
  array ('host' => $host,
    'port' => $port,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}
```

Comment: PEAR is a thing that needs to be installed, btw.

Comment: I've tried to re-word my question; to better explain, what I'm after. But great answer non the less!